# Let $G$ and $H$ be groups and let $f :G \to H$ be a group homomorphism. Show that $\ker(f)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

> Let $G$ and $H$ be groups and let $f :G \to H$ be a group homomorphism. Show that $\ker(f)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

In order for $\ker(f)$ to be normal subgroup I have to have that $\forall a \in G : a\ker(f) = \ker(f)a$?

So isn't $a\ker(f) = \{ag \in G \mid f(ag) = e_H \}$? If so then since $f$ is a homomorphism I have that $f(ag) = f(a) \cdot f(e_H) = f(a)$ and similarly $\ker(f)a = \{ga \in G \mid f(ga) = e_H \}$, but $f(ga) = f(g) \cdot f(a) = f(a)$ so $a\ker(f) = \ker(f)a$?

I'm not sure I'm going in the right direction here, what am I missing?

Comment: Unless you already know that from an earlier result, first you should prove that it is a subgroup. To prove that it is normal your proof is fine (namely $f(aga^{-1}) = f(a)f(g)f(a^{-1}) = f(a)ef(a^{-1}) = f(aa^{-1}) = f(e) = e$), but you defined $a \operatorname{ker}(f)$ wrongly.

Comment: We have $a \ker(f) = \{ag \in G \mid f(g) = e_H\}$. Note how the condition is $f(g) = e_H$, not $f(ag) = e_H$.

Comment: $a\ker(f)=\{ag\in G:g\in\ker(f)\}$. you’re definition is wrong